# providing HTML link on github

Tags: github, r-markdown, github-for-windows

I try to give an HTML link on github. HTML page is already uploaded (week3.html in below example),and I gave the link in index file.Still it does not direct me. I kindly ask your advice.
below are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update the link in the index.md file by prepending it with `https://htmlpreview.github.io/?` as below.

```
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/MEF-BDA503/pj18-gokceezeroglu/blob/master/week3.html
```

That should provide you a link which can render the html file in your repository.